# Core Data: Select entities matching certain criteria

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nssortdescriptor

Can someone give a piece of Swift code how to implement the following scenario:

Have a core date Employees with two attributes First name and Last Name, How will you sort out all the employees who's last name ends with letter 'K'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically you want to use an `NSPredicate` with `ENDSWITH` comparison

```
let term = "K"
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Employee")
let namePred = NSPredicate(format: "last_name ENDSWITH[cd] %@", term)

let people = (try context.executeFetchRequest(request) as? [Employee]) ?? []
```

Comment: Not sure this is really what he wants since the question specifies "ends with"... equally possible he asked the wrong question :)

Comment: I notice now :O going to amend the answer... selective vision :D

Comment: Thanks for the revision. ENDSWITH or BEGINSWITH will do for me. Just want to know how to achieve this. Thanks Daniele & David